# Client-side prediction for FPS

Tags: first-person-shooter

People that understand client-side prediction and client-side interpolation, I have a question:

When I play the game Team Fortress 2, and type `cl_predict 1` into the developer's console, it enables client-side prediction. The also says "6 predictable entities reinitialized". It says this regardless of how many players are on the server, which makes sense, because other players are not predictable entities.

I thought client-side prediction was only for the movement of the player. Are there other entities that the client can provide prediction for?

Comment: Those 6 predictable entities could be manager objects, like PlayerManager etc... They don't have to correspond directly with anything that you see in game. As for what can be predicted: player movement, projectile movement, hits, misses, round endings, game endings. Actually all the state that is shared via the server.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense to predict projectiles. However, for hits and misses, I'd imagine the only prediction you can do is some visual or sound feedback, you can't predict a kill, right?

Comment: Well depends on how sure you are that it's going to be a hit or miss, but most games wont do it I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side prediction can be used for everything that needs to stay synced between all players, like physics objects and bullets.  You basically run the simulation on all computers, but every so often the server "overwrites" the current state so everybody sees the same thing.

Most objects don't really need to be updated that often, and non-gameplay objects like ragdolls or particles don't need to be synced at all.